# What is this 5"-across spider found in my bedroom in France?

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

As the subject-line says, what is s/he? I've removed more spiders than I remember over the years, but one that almost fills a pint-glass was approached with some trepidation!

[image: Lateral pic of out visitor, last-week (late Summer), French Jura]

[image: Same chap, top view showing abdomen]

Comment: N.B. Found last-week (late Summer), French Jura. Sent packing to the garden...

Answer (score -1):

It looks like a type of Wolf spider https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolf_spider

Comment: We ask species ID answers to be accompanied by a confirming photograph and background details, *e.g.*  whether the location of the species matches the distribution profile of the species ID, if the size and color of the species match etc etc.

Comment: Not a wolf spider - looks more like a funnel weaver, related to the Giant house spiders. Perhaps *Aterigena ligurica*